# SWF file stops after 2nd loop

Tags: javascript, html, flash, actionscript-3, swfobject

I have a swf file which I created using Adobe Flash professional CS5.5, it's a basic animation of some birds with an audio, it is meant to reply every 5 seconds, but for some reason after it starts to play the second loop it stops mid way and restarts the video from the beginning. Can anyone help me fix this?

This is my actionscript:

```
stop();
setInterval(wait, 10000);
function wait(){
    gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

This is my javascipt to embed the movie on an html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var flashvars = {};
    var params = {};
    params.wmode = "transparent";
    var attributes = {};
    swfobject.embedSWF("/js/birdmovie.swf", "myAlternative", "290", "163", "9.0.0", "/js/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

Comment: What frame is the ActionScript in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `setInterval` because it's going to repeat indefinitely, especially if you keep creating interval at the end of your loop. Use `setTimeout` instead:

```
stop();
setTimeout(wait, 5000);
function wait(){
    gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

so it gets to the end, stops, waits 10 seconds and then goes back to the beginning, but while it's playing, it's still counting another 10 seconds, in which it will loop.

So basically use

```
setTimeout(wait, 10000);
```

rather than

```
setInterval(wait, 10000);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to name your setInterval and make sure you clear it first before starting it, otherwise you might get some unwanted confusing loops there.

```
stop();
clearInterval(my_interval);
my_interval = setInterval(wait, 10000);
function wait(){
    gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

That way it will always clear any previous interval when it goes to first frame again, avoiding multiple intervals.